# How to edit image from gridview with some other fields in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I m new to .net.

code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }         

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int index = gr.RowIndex; 
                hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString(); 
                Textid.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
                Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
                Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;


            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        }
```

When i edit the row, all fields are displayed in text box expect image filed.

Because recently i added image field, and i don't know how to edit and update image.

Here is my output [**screenshot**](http://s1.postimg.org/mi76mx5wf/untitled.jpg)

May i know, how to know about this problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: StoredProcedure1, StoredProcedure2, StoredProcedure3, StoredProcedure4?    You just flunked my class in writing good code.

Answer (score 0):

in the edit mode template, add instead of the image control a text box with the url as text property or add a fileUpload control